# Put the content of a variable in an expression

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

i want to put the content of a variable in an expression, now i explain better:
The user select a file, and i get the extension of this with

```
Dim EXTENSION as String = Path.GetExtension(Path)
```

Good, i imported in my project some png in My.Resources.
i want that a picturebox show a image according to the file extension

```
PicutureBox.Image = My.Resources.EXTENSION
```

but i can't put EXTENSION in my.resources expression. 
PS: all the resources that i imported has for the name the extension

[image]

the resource name of this file is My.Resouces.css

How can i do that?
Sorry for my bad english, i'm just an italian aged 16!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PictureBox.Image = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(EXTENSION), Image)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used your image as an example, but it will work for you

```
    Dim ext As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ext = "css" 'here is your extension
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(ext) 'here we load the file
    End Sub
```

Result :

[image]